# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "success" using ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, react-native, post

I am new to react native trying to save data to mogo db database I am getting the warning but my data is inserted in database.

My Code is as follows:

```
fetch("http://8ae1999e.ngrok.io/send-data", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name,
                email,
                phone,
                picture,
                salary,
                position
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                Alert.alert(`${data.name} is saved.`)
                navigation.navigate("Home");
            })
```

But it gives me warning

> ' JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "success" using ReactNative
>   '

while posing data and can't navigate to Home Screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch is expecting a json, but just returns the word "success" so either you return a json `{"success" : true}` or remove this line `.then(res => res.json())` so it's not expecting a json anymore

Comment: I did do the changes but can't redirect to the screen. But the data saves to data base.

Comment: use `this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")` and see if the screen "Home" exists. Does the "Alert" happen?

Comment: no alert also does not happen. it just gives the warning and stops there and also redirect to home screen with your command which doesn't happen inside the second then.

Comment: Home does exist.

Comment: Did you do what I said in my awnser? if there's still a warning after you did, then the problem it's something else

Comment: Yes I did the same but still warning is there as told in earlier comments.